Open sets and neighborhood bases in the prodiscrete topology
Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, give $Y$ the discrete topology, and give $Y^X$ the corresponding product topology, aka the prodiscrete topology.
For each $u \in Y^X$ and $\Omega \subseteq X$ define $$V(u,\Omega) = \{ v \in Y^X \mid u|_{\Omega} = v|_{\Omega} \}$$
I want to prove the following claim from Section 1.2 in Cellular Automata and Groups by Ceccherini-Silberstein and Coornaert (2010):
Problem: Show for each $u \in Y^X$ the collection
$$ \mathcal{B}(u) := \{ V(u,\Omega) \mid \Omega \subseteq X \text { and $\Omega$ is finite} \} $$
forms a neighborhood basis for $u$. Recall that $\mathcal{B}(u)$ is called a neighborhood basis if $\mathcal{B}(u) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(u)$ (the set of neighborhoods) and for every neighborhood $N \in \mathcal{N}(u)$ there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}(u)$ such that $B \subseteq N$.

For the first part, we have $u \in V(u,\Omega)$, and we should be able to show $V(u,\Omega)$ is open. To do so define for each $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ the cylinder
$$ C(x,y) := \{ u \in Y^X \mid u(x) = y \} $$
Then it is straightforward to show $$ V(u,\Omega) = \bigcap_{x \in \Omega} C(x,y) $$
So, $V(u,\Omega)$ can be expressed as a finite intersection of cylinders, which are open.
For the second part, I'm not sure where to begin. I let $N$ be a neighborhood of $u$ and I want to find a finite set $\Omega$ such that $V(u,\Omega) \subseteq N$.

So the $V(u,\Omega)$ is with the assumption that $\Omega$ is finite?

@Keen-ameteur $V(u,\Omega)$ can be defined for any $\Omega$, but $\mathcal{B}$ is defined to only contain those with finite $\Omega$

But if you take $\Omega=X$, you get that the space is actually discrete. Since every singleton can be expressed as ${u}=V(u,X)$.

@Keen-ameteur Yes, if $X$ is finite, then $Y^X$ is discrete. But I have not assumed $X$ is finite.

I thought you meant that this was the generating sub-basis of the topology or that they are all open sets. I see now that you didn't write this.

Since $N$ is a neighborhood there exists $u\in B\subseteq N$ in the base generated from finite intersections of the generating sets. The generating sets for this topology are the cylinders $C(x,y)$, so $B=\cap_{j=1}^m C(x_j,y_j)$. Take $\Omega=\cup_{j=1}^\infty\{ x_j \}$, and you can easily show that $B= V(u,\Omega)$.

Got it, the key fact is that the cylinders form a sub-basis. Thanks!
